# Python: CircularQueue doubles when size increases

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to modify the class so the capacity automatically increases when I exceed the current capacity. When trying to add to a full queue, the capacity doubles.

I have created a new list with twice the original capacity.Enqueue the items from the original list onto the new  list keeping track of the new front and back.

```
class CircularQueue:
    def __init__(self,capacity):
        self.items =[None]*capacity
        self.MAX_QUEUE = capacity
        self.front = 0
        self.back = self.MAX_QUEUE - 1
        self.count = 0

    def is_full(self):
        return self.count == self.MAX_QUEUE
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0
    def size(self):
        return self.count

    def enqueue(self,item):
            if not self.is_full():
                self.back = (self.back+1)%self.MAX_QUEUE
                self.items[self.back] = item
                self.count +=1
            else:
                double_of_self_items = len(self.items)*2
                new_list = [None]* double_of_self_items
                MAX_QUEUE = double_of_self_items
                back = MAX_QUEUE - 1
                count = 0
                back = (back + 1) % MAX_QUEUE
                new_list[back] = self.items[back]
                count += 1
                print(new_list)
                return new_list


    def dequeue(self):
            if not self.is_empty():
                item = self.items[self.front]
                self.front =(self.front+1)% self.MAX_QUEUE
                self.count -=1
                return item
            else:
                raise IndexError("The queue is empty.")

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            item = self.items[self.front]
            return item
        else:
            raise IndexError("The queue is empty.")

    def __str__(self):
        my_list = []
        for i in self.items[self.front:]:
            my_list.append(i)

        for i in self.items[:self.back + 1]:
            my_list.append(i)

        return str(my_list)




q = CircularQueue(2)
q.enqueue(10)
q.dequeue()
q.enqueue(20)
q.enqueue(30)
q.enqueue(40)
print(q.size())
print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())
print(q.dequeue())

Excepted result:
3
20
30
40

Actual Result:

[30, None, None, None]
[20, None, None, None]
[30, None, None, None]
[20, None, None, None]
[30, None, None, None]
[20, None, None, None]
2
```

Comment: You are inconsistent with what your methods return. `enqueue` for example returns either nothing or a new list. The `else` in the enqueue method is not doing what it is supposed to do. It creates a new list, but neither copies the content of the old list over nor puts the new list in place the old one so it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have the code you have, but in your `enqueue` method, simply check if you're full, increase the size if you are and then add the new item. That should simplify your logic and make your code more maintainable by having less flows.

```
def enqueue(self,item):
        if is_full():
            self.items = self.items + [None] * self.SOME_KIND_OF_INCREASE_DEFAULT
            self.MAX_QUEUE = len(self.items)

        self.back = (self.back+1)%self.MAX_QUEUE
        self.items[self.back] = item
        self.count +=1
```